# not seeing a specific resource on a web page

Tags: javascript, java, html, gwt

i have a strange problem with a web page!
and i can't see it in none of my browsers while all of my coworkers see it and work with it all well!
 
**however** if i use a vpn i can see it with no problem!
 
so i assume it is not my browser problem since i can see it contents with vpn
the ***strange part*** for me is that i can see title and html content but when it wants to fetch CSS and JS resources it gives **(failed) net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**!
i tried ping and trace rt and both of them was successful!
(*and as i said i can see title of page and it first page that is a small page*)
so i am not blocked by anything.
i also changed my internal network to something else and still it wouldn't loads up!i insert an image of what page is load in first place.
i don't know if it is relevant or not but the website is written with **GWT**
if anymore information is needed i be more than to happy too providing it.
i used firefox, chrome,edge,ie and none of them shows page!
i insert an image to show what is loaded
**html page is loaded**:
[the html page that is loaded and page content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV3Ip.jpg)

**resources that give error**:
[the resources that fail to load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCqmE.jpg) 

PS: sorry if cleared addresses out, i didn't know if it is right or not with the company to include them so i cleared them out.

Comment: it might be the browser cache issue, the details you provided are not enough - try with VPN - load your entire application first - then your browser will cache the static part of your application - and then when you will load it again without VPN it might show up

Comment: @AshishShetkar i mentioned _if i use a vpn i can see it with no problem!_ but then again if i hard reload page.. well not seeing it anymore

Comment: and also the page doesn't load in several browsers. so it is not browser related! if you need any more info i happy to share